# How safe is the idiom `ssh ... "$(typeset -f foo); foo"`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, scripting, typeset

Suppose that some shell function `foo` is defined in the current shell session.  Then the command

```
typeset -f foo
```

prints out the source code of this function.  This means that, at least in principle, one can execute this function on a remote host via `ssh` as shown below:

```
ssh <REMOTE-HOST> "$(typeset -f foo); foo"
```

(For the purposes of this question, assume that all the commands and file-system paths mentioned by `foo` are available in `<REMOTE-HOST>`.  Also, assume that `bash` is the shell on both ends.)

My instinct is that blindly sourcing some automatically generated source code like this would be extremely fragile, but I have not been able to come up with an example of a function `foo` where this idiom fails.

My question is: How safe is this idiom?  If it is not safe, can someone give me a concrete example that illustrates how it fails?  (The question of safety includes the following: does `bash` guarantee that such uses of `typeset -f` are safe?)

**NB:** In this post I am not looking for alternatives; I just want to understand the properties of this particular idiom.

---

EDIT: clarified that `bash` is the shell on both ends.

Comment: Do you know you're running the same shell on both ends?

Comment: @MichaelHomer: yes, I should have made that clear.  I just added that clarification to my post, but in short: yes, `bash` at both ends.

Comment: It seems quite weird and unconventional, though, IMO

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar: I agree, but I'm looking for a more objective rationale for opposing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not safe if the code is not interpreted in the same locale as the one where it was generated (or if the locale *name* is the same but the definition of that locale differs between the ssh client host and server host).

Particularly important is the encoding of characters and membership of characters in the `blank`, `alpha` and `alnum` categories.

For instance, the `α` character (Greek letter lower case alpha) in the BIG5 charset is encoded as 0xa3 0x5c, 0x5c being `\` in ASCII (and all charsets including BIG5).

So if you have a `foo` function defined in that charset as:

```
foo() {
  echo α
}
```

`typeset -f` will output it as such, but if interpreted in a different locale like C, that 0xa3 0x5c would not be taken as a `α` but as an unknown 0xa3 character followed by a backslash. That can be exploited like with:

```
$ env LC_ALL=zh_TW.big5 $'BASH_FUNC_foo%%=() { echo \xa3\\\\;}; echo gotcha; }' bash -c 'typeset -f foo' | bash
gotcha
bash: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash: line 5: `}'
```

The `foo() { echo α\;}; echo gotcha; }` became `foo() { echo <0xa3>\\; }; echo gotcha; }` when interpreted in the different locale.

Other problems:

The `à` character in UTF-8 is encoded as 0xc3 0xa0. In iso8859-1 and several other `iso8859` character sets, 0xa0 is the non-breaking space character. On some systems, that character is included in the *blank* character class, so honoured by bash as a token delimiter in its syntax.

Solaris is one such system where U+00A0 is considered a blank:

```
$ env $'BASH_FUNC_foo%%=() { nawk -v x=àBEGIN\'{system("echo gotcha")}\' 1;}' bash -c 'typeset -f foo; echo foo'  | ssh solaris LC_ALL=en_GB.ISO8859-1 bash
gotcha
```

See how the:

```
nawk -v x=àBEGIN... 1
```

was interpreted as:

```
nawk -v x=<0xc3> 'BEGIN{system("...")}' 1
```

Note that if the function was defined in a locale where 0xa0 was not a blank or where 0xa3 0x5c was alpha, `typeset -f` will still output it the same even if called in a locale where it's a blank (producing a different output when interpreted)

```
$ LC_ALL=zh_TW.big5 bash -c $'f() { echo \xa3\x5c$(uname); }; export LC_ALL=C; typeset -f f | bash'
bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: line 3: `    echo �\$(uname)'
```

More generally, the output of `typeset`, `alias`, `export -p`, `set`, `locale` are all **meant** to be suitable for reinput to a shell, but besides those locale issues, various implementations have been known to have several issues, and I wouldn't  be surprised if there were still many more.

So, yes, I'd agree you're right to consider it dangerous, and it's a good idea to only use them in context where you know where the data that is output comes from. For instance, in the case of `typeset -f foo`, only use it on a `foo` function that **you** have defined (and avoid using non-ASCII characters in it).